# Spark workers and master not communicating (both start without error) in standalone cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-spark

I have the same question as [Spark Clusters: worker info doesn't show on web UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851053/spark-clusters-worker-info-doesnt-show-on-web-ui) , but I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

In addition to what's written there, there are two extra interesting/useful points:

1. The workers will show up on their respective worker webuis --> http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8081/ (but not the master's (http://yyy.yy.yy.yy:8080/))
2. The workers will end in a minute or so (presumably because they can't connect to the master), without an error message.

(if I run sbin/start-slaves.sh , I see :

```
root@198.23.89.40: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /usr/local/spark/sbin/../logs/spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-alanbaresj5.hi.com.out
```

, and if I run again (without waiting for a minute or so),

```
root@198.23.89.40: org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker running as process 30542. Stop it first.
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!